# How to fix an update statement with a max function in the set clause

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I'm quite a newbie with sql-server and today I want to set a null field from my utilizzi_oggetto table with the max value of the field oggetto_pratica from the table trasco_quadri_imm; all this while the value in the column oggetto is the same in both tables. In this case trasco_oggetti_pratica, which is null, will become set at 226217.
Here's my trasco_quadri_imm table

```
OGGETTO   OGGETTO_PRATICA
1429      20310
1429      20309
1429      22110
1429      22142
1429      22111
1429      22143
1429      22144
1429      176644
1429      226216
1429      226217
```

and my utilizzi_oggetto table

```
OGGETTO     trasco_oggetto_pratica
1429         NULL
```

at my first attempt I've tried

```
update uo 
  set trasco_oggetto_pratica = max(oggetto_pratica)
  from trasco_quadri_imm tqi, utilizzi_oggetto uo
  where uo.oggetto = tqi.oggetto and uo.trasco_oggetto_pratica is null
```

but of course i can't use directly the max function in a set statement, so I modified the query into:

```
update uo
set trasco_oggetto_pratica = tqi.maxop
from utilizzi_oggetto uo JOIN
    (select max(oggetto_pratica) as maxop from trasco_quadri_imm ) tqi
where uo.trasco_oggetto_pratica is null and uo.oggetto = tqi.oggetto
```

but it gives me the error:

> Invalid column name 'oggetto'

I've also tried to put the condition in an on clause, but then I'll get the sintax's error near the word on.
I can't understand where I'm wrong and I'll thanks you in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be accomplished with a CTE, a window function like `row_number()`, `outer apply` or by simply using derived table which is probably less confusing for you. This is what you originally had, but you forgot to also return the column `oggetto` from your derived table, which is why you couldn't `join` on it and got the error.

```
update uo
set uo.trasco_oggetto_pratica = tqi.OGGETTO_PRATICA
from utilizzi_oggetto uo
inner join 
    (select 
        max(OGGETTO_PRATICA) OGGETTO_PRATICA, 
        OGGETTO 
     from trasco_quadri_imm 
     group by OGGETTO) tqi on 
    tqi.OGGETTO = uo.OGGETTO
```

Comment: i thought that the join wuold take all the fields, regardless the select; but overthinking on it and i make sense this way. Thnak for the help